# Is it possible to put the <container> block below the <header> block?

Tags: html, css

```css
header {
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  background: green;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  transform: skew(0, -10deg);
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  top: 55px;
}

.container .home{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="logo">
    <i class="fab fa-accusoft"></i>
    <span class="title">DreamCoding</span>
  </div>

  <section class="container">
    <div class="home">
      <div class="title">Alphabet</div>
      <div class="text">
        abcdefg
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

I have the  box and the  box.
I'm trying to cover the container box by the header box.
The problem is that the  box was covered by the , box again and again.

I'm not sure I explained properly cause English is not my mother tongue.
Anyway, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the `z-index` property to both the elements. Runnable code snippet below:

```css
header {
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.container {
  background: green;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  transform: skew(0, -10deg);
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  top: 55px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.container .home {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <header class="header">
    <div class="logo">
      <i class="fab fa-accusoft"></i>
      <span class="title">DreamCoding</span>
    </div>

    <section class="container">
      <div class="home">
        <div class="title">Alphabet</div>
        <div class="text">
          abcdefg
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

**The z-index property is used to make elements overlap others.

Comment: thank you for helping me. This is the best & simple solution for solving this problem. bless u.

Answer (score 0):

You can set background in `:before` selector using `position:absolute` and `z-index:-1`

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
}
header {
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
}

.container {  
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;  
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  top: 55px;
}

.container:before {
  content:"";
  transform: skew(0, -10deg);
  background: green;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position:absolute;
  top:-25px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

.container .home{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="logo">
    <i class="fab fa-accusoft"></i>
    <span class="title">DreamCoding</span>
  </div>
  <section class="container">
    <div class="home">
      <div class="title">Alphabet</div>
      <div class="text">
        abcdefg
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</header>
```

Comment: I appreciate it. i solved the problem. :) thanks x10